# Why doesn't a replacement GFCI outlet provide power?

Tags: gfci

I have a GF outlet that had no output. It did work previously. The power load coming in is 124v. I replaced it with a new GF outlet and it won't reset. There is only one outlet in line. There is no load on either outlet. What should I check

Comment: What is providing the GFCI function?

Comment: What does "only one out in line" mean? Please show a photo or we're taking wild guesses at the problem.

Comment: I edited to replace the word 'out' with 'outlet' -- If that's not what you meant, please feel free to correct it.

Comment: Most GFCIs I've seen won't reset unless they have power. Check your connections and breakers?

Comment: Clear, focused, well lit pictures of the wiring on the new receptacle would help people diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my mistake Greg.
I don't understand the question of what is providing the GFCI function. The power to the GFCI is from the breaker box. I am getting power to the outlet. I just can't reset it.

Comment: @JimStewart My hunch is "GF outlet" is shorthand for "Receptacle with integral GFCI protection".

Answer (score 3):

When wiring a GFCI outlet the pairing of the hot and neutral matters as does the positioning on the line vs load terminals. Most likely it is wired incorrectly.

Verify that the neutral and hot are paired correctly: neutral and hot from one cable or conduit going to line; neutral and hot from the other cable or conduit going to load.

Also verify that the pair that supplies the power is connected on the "line" terminals. You can use a volt meter, neon test lamp, or non-contact voltage tester (NCVT) to check.